# Trigger an event from a button in a widget

Tags: java, android, events, button, widget

I'm trying add a listener to a ImageButton that is on a widget but i can't.

My widget xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#09C"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/activityCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#09C"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"       
        android:text="Hecho"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The method that i need execute when the imageButton "activityCheck" is pressed is the next:

```
    public void changeColor(View view) {
          Log.d("changeColor", "PASE POR AQUÍ");
       ImageButton button = view.findViewById(R.id.activityCheck);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _changeColor(v);
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Isn't `android:onClick` supposed to be changeColor, the name of your method? Also, what does `_changeColor` means?

Comment: you are setting two methods on Clicking the button first you have onClick:changeButtonColor defined in your Xml then you are defining another method by setting an onClick Listener, you can immediately set your method changeColor in your xml   onClick:changeColor

Comment: Do you mean that `ImageButton` is in an App Widget?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have "android:onClick" because it's not an activity, it is a App Widget! So, I don't know how add a listener to my imageButton on the widget. The widget not handle view components but rather handles remoteView components. 
I would like to know how can add a method to my imageButton.
Thanks in advaced.

Answer (score 0):

in layout add

> android:clickable="true"

in ImageButton tag.

this will made your image clickable and then it will detect any click  events.

Comment: Hi, thanks but it work with the activity, however with a widget doesn't work.

Comment: Then you can do button.setClickable(true) , I think it will work

Comment: What happens is that this is not an activity but a widget. A widget does not handle common views but handles remote views and is supposedly done through PendingIntents and Itents. So, I don't know how to create an intent that manipulates my imageButton or button to change its color.